Kodaira vanishing + simple connectedness implies Fano
To avoid monkey business, let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety of dimension $m$. As usual, $K_X$ is its canonical line bundle. Let us further assume that $X$ is simply-connected and the following vanishing statements hold for $X$:
$$\forall n<\dim(X) \quad \forall d>0 \quad H^n (X, K_X^d) = 0,$$
$$\forall n>0 \quad  H^n (X, {\mathcal O}_X) = 0.$$
Note that if $X$ is Fano, then this vanishing follows from Kodaira vanishing. Keeping it loose, I call it Kodaira vanishing in the title.
Question 1: What is the lowest dimension $m$ where I can find such $X$, which is not Fano?
In my vabbity naivety, I expect $X$ to be incy wincy close to being Fano. It would be nice to have an extra condition that could bring $X$ over the Fano line. Hence is my second question:
Question 2: Suppose $K_X^{-1}$ is basepoint-free. Is $X$ Fano?

Consider the blowup of three collinear points on the plane.
